# Create custom MySQL Collation

Tags: mysql, internationalization, collation

can you help to create custom mysql collation?

table will contain mix of data in cyrillic and latin characters. some of data will start as a numbers.

i need to have listed (and sorted):

1. all cyrillic goes first
2. than all data with latin characters
3. at the end data that starts with a letter.

is possible to achieve it in mysql at all?

thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

The [MySQL dev site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html) gives the steps for adding a new collation. Based on your description, it would seem you could define the rules without a rebuild. If the rules are more complex, it could still be done but would be a lot more effort since it would be necessary to add the C functions for the comparisons and to rebuild MySQL

Comment: Note that that page now says that user-defined collations are deprecated.