# Is there a MySql collation that sorts Hungarian characters as per the Hungarian language rules?

Tags: mysql, collation

The **utf8mb4_hungarian_ci** not working as expected, as it puts **Á** before **A**, for example (and the opposite would be the desired order).

I have tried to figure out if there is a well working collation for Hungarian accented characters, but I did not succed. Is it still a kind of bug, or there is an other collation that is is working well?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-ce-sets.html maybe:  `latin2_hungarian_ci`   since `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`  didn't workbut it looks like it's a known bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555718/mysql-wrong-order-by-for-hungarian-characters  but you may have to create your own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308452/create-custom-mysql-collation  but it's deprecated.

Comment: does that mean the `latin2_hungarian_ci` worked as needed? or you're going in the "creating own collation" approach...

Comment: Unfortunately did not work:
COLLATION 'latin2_hungarian_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' 
Seems that own collation will be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Icelandic orders them in the opposite direction.  Meanwhile, file a bug at bugs.mysql.com and provide references.  And here is my comparison of collations: https://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html  Alas, `utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci` does not seem to be the answer, though it sorts `'A'<'Á'`, nor `utf8mb4_hu_0900_as_cs`.  (I checked 8.0.36.)

Possibly MariaDB's collation, which is based on the newer Unicode 14.0, does "the right thing".

Perhaps you wanted the accented A to sort *after* A?  See if utf8mb4_is_0900_ai_ci is a viable workaround?

See also https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12519

Comment: Hm, interesting, but I am unfortunately forced to use Mysql 8.